# How to inject the User controls onto the main window shell with prism?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ninject, prism

I've recently started learning about MVVM and WPF, and have overcome most of my problems apart from this one (I want to use a model first approach). I can't wire up all of my application's parts with PRISM and whilst also using dependency injection (with ninject).

My current understanding of MVVM with DI is as follows:

- We inject the model into the view model with constructor injection.
- the app has knowledge of which views with which view model via a resource dictionary eg

  `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ViewModel1}">
      <views:View1/>
  </DataTemplate>`
- one can assign regions to the main window shell, and swap user controls into/out of these regions.

I tried to knock up a really basic example using ninject and prism - https://github.com/ultimateshovel/wpf-mvvm-example - however I can't get the user controls to be injected into the main windows shell... I don't understand what else I need to do. I have added details of the modules to the ninject module catalog, and registered the views with the corresponding regions via a region view registry.

Specifically, I'm not sure what I need in my Custom Ninject Bootstrapper, currently I have only the following:

```
public class CustomNinjectBootstrapper : NinjectBootstrapper
{


    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Kernel.Get< Views.Shell >();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();

        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window) Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();

    }


    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();

        var textModule = typeof( TextModule );
        var buttonModule = typeof( ButtonModule );

        ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo(textModule.Name, textModule.AssemblyQualifiedName));
        ModuleCatalog.AddModule(new ModuleInfo(buttonModule.Name, buttonModule.AssemblyQualifiedName));
    }
}
```

I assume that I'm going to need to use a RegionManager, but I'm not sure how those work in a context which isn't view injection.

I suspect that I may also need to add things to the Initialize methods of my modules, which currently look like so

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        _regionViewRegistry.RegisterViewWithRegion
            ( "TextRegion", typeof( TextView ) );
    }
```

but again, i'm not sure what

Comment: Please make your question more specific, and include the part of the code you're having trouble with within the question itself, rather than linking to it somewhere else

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. You have a lot of concepts incorrect. You should really start learning more about MVVM (model first is not a thing). To learn how to properly use Prism, I suggest starting with the documentation (http://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and reviewing the samples (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf). You can even watch this pluralsight course https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/prism-introduction